# how does vans have a small-sized json 3d model

Tags: json, reactjs, three.js, gltf, react-three-fiber

I am trying to create a 3d site using Threejs and React and react-three-fiber where I can customize shirts and then stumbled upon vans website in their customization page. I noticed that they are not using gltf but instead just use json and it's quite small for the quality of the 3d it shows. I was wondering how they achieved such file size for such quality. Because compared to mine I have a gltf that amounts to more or less 5mb but when I converted it to json using the .toJSON in threejs it became 100mb.

I looked into the request and this is the size:
[image]

this is the json data that it responds:
[image]

and this is the 3d representation:
[image]

Currently I am using gltf to load the 3d but I am trying to replicate vans' way and just request a json data from the server but the json data the I can achieve is just to big.
How did they do it?

Apparently only the geometry matters to me.
If anyone has any idea about what they did on this.. I am more than thankful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This model has one or more textures, and I think it's almost certain that textures account for most of the size difference you are seeing when converting from glTF to three.js custom JSON format. Writing textures into a Data URI (for JSON serialization) in a browser can sometimes create a very unoptimized version of an image.

My suggestion would be to stick with the glTF file — a more efficient format, and [three.js itself recommends it](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models) — and use [glTF optimization tools](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/gltf-optimization/22391) to bring the size down further or compress the texture.

Comment: thanks for answering my question I appreciate it a lot. Uhm just an additional question. is there a way to separate the Geometry from the textures or materials. like only include the geometry in exporting.. Because apparently I only need the geometry in my app.. thanks again

Comment: That should be possible, yes — for example `scene.children[0].geometry.toJSON()` would be one option. Or you can potentially open the glTF model in Blender and detach the materials and textures, then export it again.

Comment: actually I am using .glb file compressed with draco upon exporting from blender.. I've unchecked all other options in exporting except the geometry part.. checked UVs Normals, Vertex Colors and set the material to Export.. and the result that I get is about 11mb in size which is quite decent but if there is any other way that I could still reduce its file size during request like the one in vans... I am using blender 2.92.. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: There are other tools available (see the links above) but probably a longer conversation than comments allow. If you can share the model on the three.js forums you might be able to get more specific suggestions. :)

Comment: That is great. Thank you so much. you will surely hear from me soon in the three.js forums.. I appreciate your support :)